# How does DAEMON(3) work? Run as background process

Tags: python, daemon

What are step to make the process detach from the terminal? For that I found man page of [`daemon()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) In the description, they mentioned

> If nochdir is zero, daemon() changes the process's current working
>          directory to the root directory ("/"); otherwise, the current working
>          directory is left unchanged.
>
> If noclose is zero, daemon() redirects standard input, standard
>          output and standard error to /dev/null; otherwise, no changes are
>          made to these file descriptors.

Actually, I was trying to make my python code run as daemon. I found `tcollector` code [here](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/tcollector/blob/master/tcollector.py#L962). In that code also they are following same steps like in the description of `daemon()`. So my question is, why should we do those steps (w.r.t [`daemonize()`](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/tcollector/blob/master/tcollector.py#L962) in `tcollector`) like

why change `dir` to `/`, `umask` to `022` and then calling `os.setsid()`, etc.

Comment: Are you asking why does `tcollector` do all that dance instead of calling `daemon(3)`?  Then the answer is: because `daemon(3)` is Linux-specific, while `daemonize()` in `tcollector` works on any UNIX system.

Comment: Or, are you asking what all the steps are for, those in `daemon(3)` and those in that python code? Or about their differences..?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking about steps in `daemon(3)`, seem like that is standard and that's why they have used same steps in Python code also. How can I detach process from terminal with those steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually more there than what you quoted, but I think that manual page could be clearer.

> If nochdir is zero, `daemon()` changes the process's current working
>          directory to the root directory (`/`)

The assumption here is that the program is started from an administrators command line, and the idea is to disassociate the daemon from what the admin was doing at the time. Changing the working directory to `/` prevents the daemon from keeping a mount point busy. E.g. if the working directory was `/home/admin` and some time later you wanted to unmount `/home`, the daemon would prevent that.

> If noclose is zero, `daemon()` redirects standard input, standard
>          output and standard error to `/dev/null`;

This is to prevent the daemon from confusing users by writing stray error messages or such to their terminal. What the daemon probably should do, is to open some (configured) log file, and write there whatever it wants to communicate to the outside.

> (This function forks, and if the fork(2) succeeds, the parent calls
>          _exit(2), so that further errors are seen by the child only.)

Again, to disassociate from the admins shell session, the main program returns immediately, and the other part stays in the background, so no need to explicitly ask for the program to be started in the background (e.g. `./daemon &`)

Now, what the manual page doesn't explicitly tell, but implies here (under BUGS):

> The GNU C library implementation of this function was taken from BSD,
>          and does not employ the double-fork technique (i.e., fork(2),
>          setsid(2), fork(2)) that is necessary to ensure that the resulting
>          daemon process is not a session leader.  Instead, the resulting
>          daemon is a session leader.

`daemon()` also calls [`setsid()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html) to release itself from the session's [controlling terminal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_115), and therefore from the signals sent by the terminal. But as the quote there says, this leaves the possibility that if it opens a terminal device, it may accidentally get that as a controlling terminal instead. To avoid that, some programs call `fork()`, then `setsid()` from the child, and then fork again, exiting both parents so that the resulting process is not a session leader (the middle one is/was), and cannot get a controlling terminal. The Python program you refer to does exactly that.

Changing the `umask` doesn't seem to be that related to daemonizing. Perhaps that program has a particular need for it.